# Questions about if, when, while statements

Tags: modelica

I would like to write a loop whose function is that when the value of c is less than 0.1, the loop terminates and outputs the value at the moment.
Here's the code I wrote, I don't know when or while to use, thanks in advance for your reply

```
model Unnamed
 Real a;
 Real b;
 Real c(start=2);

algorithm 


 while abs(c)>0.1 loop
  a:=2*time-0.5;
  b:=time+0.1;
  c:=a-b;
 //  break;
 end while;

end Unnamed;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand the algorithm and while-loop isn't important.

What you want is to simulate as long as abs(c)>0.1 and then stop!

That can be done as follows:

```
model Unnamed
 Real a;
 Real b;
 Real c(start=2);
algorithm 
 a:=2*time-0.5;
 b:=time+0.1;
 c:=a-b;
 when not abs(c)>0.1 then
   terminate("Reached end");
 end when;
end Unnamed;
```

This will stop after 0.5s. And as @marco noted it is generally preferable to use an equation instead of an algorithm - so just write:

```
model Unnamed
 Real a;
 Real b;
 Real c(start=2);
equation 
 a=2*time-0.5;
 b=time+0.1;
 c=a-b;
 when not abs(c)>0.1 then
   terminate("Reached end");
 end when;
end Unnamed;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is syntactically correct and the model simulates. However, the loop never ends, as it computes always the same values.

During initialization, we have `time=0`, hence the loop evaluates to:

```
 while abs(c)>0.1 loop
  a := -0.5;
  b := +0.1;
  c := a -b; // = -0.6;
 end while;
```

As you see, it will run forever.

The question is what you really want to compute. `while` loops are rarely used in Modelica models. Also `algorithm` sections should be avoided. If possible, use equations defined in the `equation` section instead.

If you have to use the `while` loop, you have to make sure that it terminates.

1. Formulate your conditions such that this is possible
2. As a backup, abort the simulation after a certain number or runs, instead of running forever

```
model Unnamed

 Real a, b;
 Real c(start=2);
 Integer i;
 constant Integer maxIterations = 1000000;

algorithm 

 a := 2*time+0.5;
 b := time;
 c := a - b;
 i := 0;

 while abs(c)>0.1 and i < maxIterations loop
  i := i + 1;
  b := b + 0.1;
  c := a - b;
 end while;

 assert(i < maxIterations, "Maximum number of iterations exceeded");

end Unnamed;
```

- Unlike your code, `a` is initialized positive here
- `b` is increased with every loop, so the while condition will turn to false
- variables which do not change are assigned outside the loop
- `maxIterations` and `assert` are used to terminate with an error, instead of running forever
  *(In case we made a mistake in our algorithm. Here we did not consider that `time` can be negative in Modelica. With a simulation start time of -1 the assert is triggered.)*

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I don't think you understood what I meant. I want to write a loop that can be terminated when the loop condition is not met. As I wrote the code, if c<0.1, I want the loop to terminate and output the value at the moment

Comment: Not sure what you mean with terminate. `terminate` is used in Modelica to stop the simulation. Do you mean to stop the loop? It exits automatically as soon as the condition is not met.